# How to convert xml layouts to image?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

In my Android project I have more than 100 xml layouts.
Is there a function in Android Studio where I can screenshot my layout?
I want to convert all my layouts to jpeg or png for my company report.

Comment: If you have 100 layouts, you did something massively wrong.

Comment: what's the wrong?

Comment: I'd need to know what you were using them for to tell you.  But I've written very complicated apps with dozens of screens, and they didn't have 100 layouts.  Even when including layouts for individual views.

Comment: Okay, just imagine 3 layouts.
I need just picture of these layouts.

Comment: Run the app and take a screenshot using the screenshot functionality of your phone/device.  There's no way to just picture the layout without running the app.  It wouldn't be accurate if you could-  it would have no data.

Answer (score 0):

In this function you just have to pass the view it will give you bitmap you can store it or show it on imageview

```
public void takeScreenshot(View screenshotView) {

        try {

            View view = null;

            Bitmap b = null;
            if (screenshotView instanceof TextureView) {
                b = ((TextureView) screenshotView).getBitmap();
            } else {
                view = screenshotView;
            }
            if (view != null) {
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                view.buildDrawingCache();
                b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            }
            if (imageViewParentLayout != null) {
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
                }
            }
            String path = saveToAlbum(b);
            Notify.INSTANCE.Toast("Image Saved :" + path);
            scanfiles(path);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Notify.INSTANCE.Toast("Something Went Wrong");
        }finally {
            hideImageView();
        }
    }



private void scanfiles(String path) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                File outputFile = new File(path);
                final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
                scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                AppController.getAppContext().sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
            } else {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
                AppController.getAppContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            File file=new File(path);
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(AppController.getAppContext(), new String[]{

                            file.getAbsolutePath()},

                    null, (path1, uri) -> {


                    });
        }

    }
```